# Magento Hacked 302 Redirect From Google

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, redirect, malware

I have a Magento webshop, which from Search engines redirects to spammy / wrong website.

The original link is http://example.com that redirects to http://www.example2.com/ but only from search engines.

If you enter the link directly in the browser it goes to the site correctly.

So it seem it's hacked and it could be the htaccess file, but there is nothing suspicious in it at all.

The question is then where and how do I find where the possible redirect is made ? Imagine it could be some sort of php code inserted? How do I in an easy find the spammy code doing this redirect?

There is nothing in index.php either.

Comment: Do you have shell access? If you do, try doing `grep -HRi "amawatches" /path/to/your/home/directory`. However finding what files were hacked will not solve the problem. You need to change your password and see if there are any other sort of vulnerabilities that are letting the hackers get in and plug up the holes or else they will just do it again.

Comment: I don't have shell access, unfortunately. is there any other way ?

Comment: See my edited comment. If you don't have shell access you could download all of the files to your local computer and do a search for files containing that text.

Comment: Also seeing that you're using `eval` (*facepalm*), it could also be code stored somewhere in your database.

Comment: On another note, I was able to download your site with curl and this just happened to be the first line I looked at: `<script src="https ://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/blob/master/dist/html5shiv.js"></script>`. You should probably fix that by removing the space.

Comment: @Mike many thanks, it all worked and corrected the error you noticed also. Thanks.

Comment: So what exactly happened?

Comment: It was within the eval method that hellcode pointed out in config.php.

Comment: Just another reason not to use `eval()`

Comment: _hellcode_ Yep, that's our little buddy `eval()`, many's the php scripter using it that finds it can be brutally malicious if passed the wrong user generated or manipulable content. Taint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you request your site without user agent, you will get:

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: HTTP_USER_AGENT in <b>/var/www/coolslips.dk/public_html/includes/config.php(2) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(2) : eval()'d code</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: HTTP_USER_AGENT in <b>/var/www/coolslips.dk/public_html/includes/config.php(2) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(2) : eval()'d code</b> on line <b>4</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: HTTP_USER_AGENT in <b>/var/www/coolslips.dk/public_html/includes/config.php(2) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(2) : eval()'d code</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: HTTP_USER_AGENT in <b>/var/www/coolslips.dk/public_html/includes/config.php(2) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(2) : eval()'d code</b> on line <b>6</b><br />
<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href = 'http://coolslips.dk/errors/report.php?id=1151386284028&skin=default';</script>
```

So have a look at /var/www/coolslips.dk/public_html/includes/config.php

---

And have a look at your /news folder. It seems that there a some html files (e.g. /news/A-Lange.html)

Comment: Looking into it now, many thanks. Will let you know when it works.